# How to correctly use Data Annotations to select which Items should be returned by the Web API?

Tags: data-annotations, asp.net-web-api2, circular-reference, ef-database-first

I'm trying to specify a subset of data to be returned from a database query by Web API 2. 
In particular, for this query, I first turn lazy loading on:

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

This is because there are potentially infinite levels of children. For example:

```
Parent: {"name":"Jon","children":[{"name":"Dave","children":["name":"Ed"...
```

Each person in the above sequence can also have a biography. In the database, the books also have related tables for, let's say, authors, reviewers etc.

As far as I know I can add data annotations to the model to specify which fields to return:

```
[Key]
```

= specifies the key which will be returned

```
[DataMember]
```

= specifies a property which will be returned

```
[JsonIgnore]
[IgnoreDataMember]
```

= specifies a property which will not be returned

```
[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]
```

= specifies that the object is being references from another object and therefore related objects should not be loaded

I'm struggling to load the related biographies. The id for the biography is returning, but the biography objects are null. From the parent object, I have annotated both the nullable int and the virtual object references to biography with `[DataMember]`. In the biography object, I have then specified the id with `[Key]` and the name with  `[DataMember]` and all other properties with `[JsonIgnore]
[IgnoreDataMember]`. However the biographies are not being loaded. The db query is returning the items loaded, but they are then being nulled by web api, I assume because of some circular reference in the chain somewhere.

There are about 50 tables linked in some way, do I need to go through them all and add data annotations to everyone - even if  I have used an ignore annotation to break the chain? Hoping for a simple solution, but any solution appreciated!

It seems to be working fine that `[DataMember]` will load a HashSet of related data, which gets instantiated in the constructor, but related databases objects (which are not instantiated in the constructor) do not get loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the update statement doesn't turn lazy loading on:

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

The related items would only be returned if I went into debug mode and loaded the related data when hovering over the object (seems strange), but basically it was staying in lazy loading = false mode.

My solution has been to turn lazy loading on globally and to use data annotations as described above to avoid circular references.